# Cleaner way to define methods without lambdas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, closures, metaprogramming

Is there an **easier and/or more readable** way to create a **closure** in Ruby so that the defined method has **access to the variable** `m`?

I have a slight "problem" with the `lambda` here.

Very often I dynamically define methods that have to access a local variable:

For example:

```
class Comparison

  def income
    123
  end

  def sales
    42342
  end

  # and a dozen of other methods

  # Generate xxx_after_tax for each method
  instance_methods(false).each do |m|
    lambda {
      define_method("#{m}_after_tax") do
        send(m) * 0.9
      end
    }.call
  end
end
```

Comment: are you sure that lambda is required? the closure should work just fine without it.

Comment: he doesn't need lambda here)) and this is looks very funny, creating lambda and instantly calling it. Lambda is just an anonymus function.

Comment: Yes, it is. Lambda is required to have access to the `m` variable inside the method definition.

Comment: I don't know which Ruby are you using, but neither 1.8.7 or 1.9.3 need this lambda.

Comment: Ignore that. It actually works without lambda. Can't remember now when and why I started to wrap it in lambdas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Comparison

  def income
    123
  end

  def sales
    42342
  end

  # and a dozen of other methods

  # Generate xxx_after_tax for each method
  instance_methods(false).each do |m|

    define_method("#{m}_after_tax") do
      send(m) * 0.9
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: You cannot do it because you will have no access to variable `m` from the implementation.

Comment: did u try that? it works...and using lambda here is overkill because u didn't pass variables to lambda, and doesn't make any sense at all)). define_method it is just a function which u call inside iterator, so arguments can include any vars in iterator scope

Comment: @DmytriiNagirniak This is the right answer, I have a minimal test case in my answer which you can try for yourself.

Comment: Indeed, that is true. I don't understand why I have been using `lambda`. There definitely were situations where it _was_ required. But can't remember now...

Answer (score 3):

Regular method definitions are not closures, but here you are calling `define_method` with a block, and blocks *are* closures. This should be sufficient:

```
instance_methods(false).each do |m|
  define_method :"#{m}_after_tax" do
    send(m) * 0.9
  end
end
```

Comment: I think I gave bad example. So if I would be defining method from a method I would need to create a closure (with lambda or block)? Right?

Comment: @Dmytrii, if you need to capture the local variables available in a given context, you must create a closure. The issue here is that you are creating two: a `lambda` and the block given to `define_method`. The former is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

As Yuri points out, the `lambda` is redundant, which you can see by running this example.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -w

class Foo
  [:foo, :bar].each do |m|
    define_method("#{m}_dynamic") do
      "Called #{m}"
    end
  end
end

p Foo.new.foo_dynamic # => "Called foo"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  instance_methods(false).each do |m|
    class_eval <<-ERUBY, __FILE__, __LINE__
      def #{m}_after_tax
        #{m} * 0.9
      end
    ERUBY
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use method_missing like this:

```
def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
  if name.to_s.match /^([a-z_]+)_after_tax$/
    send($1)
  else
    super
  end
end
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: There's no need at all to use method_missing. It complicates things. You also have to implement respond_to? and related. It's absolutely overkil here.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why I would have to implement respond_to?

Comment: http://technicalpickles.com/posts/using-method_missing-and-respond_to-to-create-dynamic-methods/